# How to list dependencies of an artifact in Nexus OSS?

Tags: maven, repository, devops, nexus

Is there a plugin or setting that I can configure Nexus OSS 3.58.1-01 to list all dependencies of a selected artifact?

I am expecting it should behave as `mvnrepository.com`

[image]

Comment: I believe it's only available in Pro version. That being said, it's "only" an extraction of what's defined in the POM file. Depending on what you're looking for, you could download the POM and get the information.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I found that Apache Archiva supports this feature. So, I switched to using it instead of Nexus OSS.